# Parameter kind of "%Type" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

So I was using Oracle before and when I want to create a parameter that has the same datatype as the datatype of an attribute in the table for a stored procedure or a function, I can use like

```
Create or replace procedure procedure__name(p_parameter Table.Attribute%TYPE)
```

I wonder if we have any kind of copy datatype like this in SQL Server also? (I did try `Create procedure (@p_parameter Table.Attribute%TYPE)` but of course it doesn't work). Or I have to specify the datatype for each of my parameter?

Comment: Ahh shook, I didn't know I need to accept the answer to all my questions, I'll accept them now.

Comment: There is no equivalent in SQL Server, you have to specify manually - out of interest, in Oracle, how do you link a parameter to a table column in order for it to obtain the type automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not in SQL Server. It's not part of standard ANSI SQL.

Comment: It may not be part of ANSI SQL but since when has that stopped Microsoft? It's a very useful feature that I constantly miss from my Oracle days.